# How do I learn hacking?

Tags: professional-education

I am 15 years old. I want to be a hacker. Can you give me advice on what to start or what to learn as

Comment: Hi Mi, welcome to Security.SE! Unfortunately your question is too broad and is opinion based, since this is a broad field and every person learns their way through it their own way. As such, it cannot be answered here and will likely be closed very soon.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vj96QetfTg "How the Best Hackers Learn Their Craft". RSA Conf video. Answer: Capture the Flag - lots of challenges.

Answer (score 1):

Information Security is such a broad field; every aspect of a computer from networking to printer firmware to image rendering to cryptography is a potential point of attack. An expert in firewalls and network security, and an expert in pen-testing drivers and firmware are both security experts, but have almost no overlapping knowledge.

My advice is to start with a technology you understand well, and start learning about common attacks against it. If you know networks well, then start learning about the details of firewalls, port scanners, etc. If you know the details of how jpeg and png compression and file formats work, then pick a few CVEs targeting image renderers and try writing code to exploit those CVEs.

Pick a technology you already know well and start you learning there.